# Mageto1.9 : custom module saveAction() not working for new form

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

I have created a custom module, It was working before, but now when I'm trying to create new form it is not generating id even previously creating form updating successfully.

I checked in `saveAction()` function all fields values are proper and after `$model->save()` I checked all fields have values except `id`.

Please guide me how to solve this issue?

```
public function saveAction() 
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost())
        {
            /* for multiselect fields */    
            Mage::log(print_r($data, 1), null, 'test.log');
            foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_array($value))
                {
                    $data[$key] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam($key)); 
                }
            }  

            $model = Mage::getModel('custom/module');       
            $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

            try
            {   
                $model->save();

                Mage::log(print_r($model->getdata(), 1), null, 'test.log');

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Saved successfully.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) 
                {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'),'id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'),'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }   
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('custom')->__('Unable to find block to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

I'm getting success message, but no id generated from the `$model`.

Comment: can you please set save code in question so easy to identify error.

Comment: @Magento2Devloper, Please check my edited question.

Comment: why you save id magento create auto increment id.

Comment: wel come. keep it up.